# Using https and SSL with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, openssl

I've run into bit of a problem with setting up my self-signed certificate to test out how it all works. I found a nice gist on GitHub : https://gist.github.com/trcarden/3295935#file-gistfile1-sh-L17
explaining how to do it simply enough.

It errors out on step 3, when entering this command into the Rails console:

```
$ openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

The problem I run into is the following:

```
Unable to load config info from /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

This is an output from the Rails console and it seems as a pretty standard error when searching for it on the internet. I've found lots of Q&A threads on various sites but absolutely nothing I've managed to find does the trick.

Any advice on what do try out to solve this ? Thanks

Comment: I think your server has this config in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`. If it’s a case, the simplest and fastest fix would be: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/ssl /etc/ssl`.

Comment: Seems not, I get: creating symbolic link `/etc/ssl' to `/usr/local/ssl': No such file or directory

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mixed the arguments up. It must be of course: `sudo ln -s /etc/ssl /usr/local/ssl`. Sorry for that.

Comment: Unforunately still the same thing...Let me make a little digression. For now I've decided to use a generic self-signed certificate created over the web for app testing. Could you tell me how to use the .cert and .key files with my app ? @mudasobwa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that has an issue like this, the problem was with using the rails WEBrick library for the server. I'm not sure exactly why, but simply switching to [**Thin server**](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/) and using the 
`thin start --ssl` command **instead of** `force_ssl` with WEBrick fixed  the issue. Feel free to post any additional info if you know of any reasons.